# PHP Calculator that will continuously compute

Tags: php

The only remaining issue is that when I try and complete a second computation using the value from the previous calculation as the beginning value, the answer is always 0. What else needs to be done in order to just continuously compute equations?

```
<html>
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['num1']= 0;
$num1 = $_SESSION['num1'];
if(isset($_POST['num1'])){
    $num1 = $_POST['num1'];
}
if(isset($_POST['num2'])){
    $num2 = $_POST['num2'];
}
if(isset($_POST['calcu'])){
   $calcu = $_POST['calcu'];
}

function calculate($n1,$n2,$calcu){
    switch($calcu)
    {
    case "Addition":
        $compute = $n1 + $n2; 
        break;
    case "Subtraction":
        $compute = $n1 - $n2; 
        break;
    case "Multiplication":
        $compute = $n1 * $n2; 
        break;
    case "Division":
        $compute = $n1 / $n2; 
        break;
    }
    return $compute;
}
// echo "$calcu <br /> <br /> Beginning Number: $num1 <br /> Next Number: $num2 <br /><br />";
 echo "Answer is:" .calculate($num1,$num2, $calcu);
 $_SESSION['num1']=calculate($num1, $num2, $calcu);
?>
<body>
<form action=<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?> method="post">
    Beginning Number:<?php echo $_SESSION['num1'];?><br>
    Next Number: <input type="number"name="num2"><br>
    Calculation: Please type one of the following- Addition, Subtraction, Multiplication, or Division. <input type="text" name="calcu"><br>
    <input type="submit"><br>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: After each calculation, store the value in session and it will be available to reuse in the next calculation

Comment: @MarkBaker I'm sorry, but I am not sure what you mean by storing it in a session, this is an online class with no book or lectures, and our instructor tells us to just Google things which doesn't always help.

Comment: [Good place to start](http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php)

Comment: I have looked into the sessions and using registered_globals, however, from reading the PHP manual, PHP no longer supports using registered_globals, so is there any other way to start and display $num1 = 0 in the form and then have $num1 update to the value after the first computation?

Comment: Don't use registered_globals, not only aren't they supported any more, but they're not persistent; and what you need is persistence between requests.... sessions (or another datastore like a database or a file) is the answer to what you want to achieve

Comment: after reading up on the php session functions, I have updated my code and I still get that num1 is an undefined variable although I have defined it and assigned it a value.

Comment: Edit your question with the current code that you have

Comment: Place session_start() at the very top first....

Comment: okay so I have eliminated all of the undefined variable issues, now my issue is that when I try a second calculation using the value from the first calculation as the first number, the answer just gives a zero...I have updated my initial post to edit and show my current code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your code:

```
$_SESSION['num1']= 0;
$num1 = $_SESSION['num1'];
```

Since you've just assigned 0 to `$_SESSION['num1']`, `$num1` will always end up zero as well.

You probably want to wrap that first assignment in a conditional:

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['num1'])) {
    $_SESSION['num1'] = 0;
}
```

Comment: Wow I cannot believe I overlooked that! That totally solved the issue I had thanks so much